# Hypothesis Testing and Rejection Region Problem

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Assume $X_i$, where $i=1,..,n$, is random sample from normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown. Suppose we use $C = \frac{\bar X_n}{S_n} \gt k$ as the rejection region under $H_0: \mu=0$ against $H_a: \mu \gt 0$. Try to find the k value if we let $\alpha = 0.1$, and try to verify whether this is LRT.

I only know that I should let $P(\frac{\bar X_n}{S_n} \gt k)=0.1$, but I don't know what to do next. Any help or hint would be helpful

Comment: Assuming $\mu=0$ the random variable $T=\frac{\bar{X}}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ possesses a Student's $T$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\bar{X}}{S}>k\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(T>k\sqrt{n}\right)=0.1$$ whenever $k\sqrt{n}$ equals the critical value $t_{n-1,0.1}$.

Comment: Thanks! If there is any hint for the second part?